# Is there a better way to implement a time consuming splash screen loader?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, splash-screen

I have an application that uses many controls which can take a very long time to intitialize (On the order of 10 to 30 seconds).  So I use a splash screen for my application to load them up and present the user with some sense of satisfaction that something is happening.  I display a spinning gif and a progress bar.

Because I am pre-loading controls, it seemed the only way to do this was on the main UI thread.  Then I discovered Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.  Now I do my spalsh screen like this.

**Program.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Spectrum.Foxhunt.Forms;
using Spectrum.UI;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;

namespace Spectrum.Foxhunt
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            new SplashLoader().Run(args);
        }
    }

    class SplashLoader : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
    {
        private Main main;
        private Splash splash;

        public SplashLoader()
        {
            main = new Main();
            splash = new Splash();
        }

        protected override void OnCreateSplashScreen()
        {
            this.SplashScreen = splash;
        }

        protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
        {
            main.SplashScreenWork(splash);
            this.MainForm = main;
        }
    }
}
```

**Splash.cs:**

Just a form with a graphic that represents my application, version information, a spinning gif, and a progress bar.

```
namespace Spectrum.Foxhunt.Forms
{
    public partial class Splash : Form
    {
        public int Progress { set { progress.Value = value; } }

        public Splash()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            version.Text = "Version " + typeof(Main).Assembly.GetName().Version;
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.cs:**

Has an empty constructor and my method which does all the work while the splash screen is displayed.

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void SplashScreenWork(Splash splash)
{
    // Create time-consuming control
    splash.Progress = 25;
    // Create time-consuming control
    splash.Progress = 50;
    // Create time-consuming control
    splash.Progress = 75;
    // Create time-consuming control
    splash.Progress = 100;
}
```

I like this method because it seems to eliminate of the threading issues I was having with trying to do this work in a background worker.  And, my spinnning gif in the splash form continues to spin despite all the work going on in the background.

That being said, I wonder if there is a better way to implement a splash screen that is loading controls while still allowing a spinning gif to spin and a progress bar to update on the splash screen.

Comment: With **a lot** of thinking about what will happen all around and after you did think about it at least 3 times you may use Application.DoEvents().

Comment: Have you considered creating the time-consuming controls on their own threads?

Comment: What about the UI controls takes so long?  The data or the actual control?

Comment: Splash screen shouldn't be married to control creation. Display it while Main loads - and hide it when Main (and it's associated controls) are done. This includes not trying to report progress, which is rarely worth the annoyance for programmer or user.

Comment: @Adriano I was originally do Application.DoEvents().  But I really try to avoid using that at all.  And I figured that has to be a better way.

Comment: @BobKaufman Problem with doing that is that any future calls to the control when the UI is touched do not work without invoking the controls.  Messy.

Comment: @Blam They are map controls.  GMap.NET specifically.  The long load time is based on checking for an active internet connection, downloading tiles, populating the map from cached tiles, etc.  This all happens within the GMap.NET dll in the constructor of the control and I have no way of threading any of the operations.

Comment: @JohnArlen Really wany to report progress as it can take upwards of 2 full minutes for the application is load.  Need the user to know things haven't blown up.

Comment: So they are UI controls?  Bummer.  Too bad they are designed that way.  I still would not splash screen to report progress.

Comment: @Blam Well the above method works and works beautifully.  I was just curious if there is a "better" way to do it.  Fair enough that your suggestion is "not" to do it at all.  :-)  But in my case with the up to 2 minute loading time I feel like I really need to give some type of progress indication.

Comment: Just cause I would not do it that way does not mean it is wrong.  I just like less moving parts.

Comment: Just looked up GMap.NET and it is open source.  Where is your sense of adventure?  Rewrite it to get data on backgournd thread and pass it to the constructor on the UI thread.  Then you could even use parallel threads for the data.  ;)